# How to use Azure Open Data with PHP

Tags: php, json, azure

I am trying to use this webservice from the RDW. You can use it to get information about a car by providing its license plate number. This is the link I use.

```
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('xnrr85')?$format=json
```

xnrr85 is a licence plate for example.

But how do I get this information in a PHP script? I tried a couple of things but it doesn't seem to get the JSON data.

This is the current script;

```
/*
$queryUrl = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('xnrr85')?$format=json";
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $queryUrl);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,  true);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);


$response = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

print_r($response);
*/

$url = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('xnrr85')?$format=json";
$JSON = file_get_contents($url);

// You can decode it to process it in PHP
$data = json_decode($JSON);
var_dump($data);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update:** I thought it was a typo, but yes, it indeed is working:

```
$url = "https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('xnrr85')?\$format=json";
$response = json_decode(file_get_contents($url), true);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($response);
```

You just need to escape that `$` inside that quotes.

```
\$format=json
^ // so that it won't search for that variable since it will be interpolated.
```

Or escape the single quotes:

```
$url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT(\'xnrr85\')?$format=json';
                                                                            ^         ^ and treat `$` as literal string
```

Comment: The parameter is ?$format=json.

This link works;
https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT('xnrr85')?$format=json

Comment: @Student oh i thought it was a typo, anyways, its working you just need to escape that `$` because of that double quotes

Answer (score 1):

Replace your url with following

```
$url = 'https://api.datamarket.azure.com/opendata.rdw/VRTG.Open.Data/v1/KENT_VRTG_O_DAT(\'xnrr85\')?$format=json';
```